# How do I get the transloadit final link saved on the file's storage server (as in Google Cloud Storage) back to the component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, uppy, transloadit

I'm trying to figure out how to get the final link saved in google storage (starting with "https://storage.googleapis.com/...") in a React component, but the Doc is not so clear.

In the ok value of the transloadit object (in result console) I keep getting "ASSEMBLY_UPLOADING" and not "ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED" even if the file was successfully uploaded.

```
 uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
     console.log(result)
   })
```

.

```
// UppyDashboard.tsx

'use client'

import themeModeState from '@/recoils/themeMode/themeModeState'
import '@uppy/core/dist/style.css'
import '@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css'
import { Dashboard } from '@uppy/react'
import '@uppy/url/dist/style.css'
import * as React from 'react'
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import createUppy from '@/components/uppy/createUppy'

export interface IUppyDashboard {
 // ...
}

const UppyDashboard: React.FC<IUppyDashboard> = ({
  templateId,
  authKey,
  authSecret,
}) => {
  const themeMode = useRecoilValue(themeModeState)
  const houseId = 'mainHouse'
  const roomId = 'mainRoom'
  const [uppy] = useState(() =>
    createUppy({
      ids: {
        houseId,
        roomId,
      },
      authKey,
      authSecret,
      templateId,
    })
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (houseId && roomId) {
      uppy.setOptions({ meta: { houseId, roomId } })
    }
  }, [uppy, houseId, roomId])

  uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })

  return (
          <Dashboard
            uppy={uppy}
            plugins={[
              // 'Webcam',
              'Dropbox',
              'GoogleDrive',
              'Facebook',
              'OneDrive',
              'Box',
              'Url',
            ]}
            metaFields={[
              { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'Image name' },
              {
                id: 'caption',
                name: 'Caption',
                placeholder: 'Describe what the image is about',
              },
            ]}
            showLinkToFileUploadResult={false} 
            waitForThumbnailsBeforeUpload={true} 
            showSelectedFiles={true}
            replaceTargetContent={true}
            showProgressDetails={false} 
            note="Images only, 1–4 files, up to 5 MB"
            height="350px" // 
            width="auto" // 
            theme={themeMode || 'auto'} 
          />
    />
  )
}

export default UppyDashboard
```

.

```
// createUppy.tsx

import Compressor from '@uppy/compressor'
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import Url from '@uppy/url'
import GoogleDrive from '@uppy/google-drive'
import Facebook from '@uppy/facebook'
import OneDrive from '@uppy/onedrive'
import Dropbox from '@uppy/dropbox'
import Box from '@uppy/box'
import ImageEditor from '@uppy/image-editor'
// @ts-ignore
import Hebrew from '@uppy/locales/lib/he_IL'
import Transloadit, { COMPANION_URL } from '@uppy/transloadit'
import expires from './dateString'
import createSignature from './transloaditSignature'

type CreateUppy = {
  ids: {
    houseId: string
    roomId: string
  }
  authKey: string
  authSecret: string
  templateId: string
}

const createUppy = (props: CreateUppy) => {
  const { ids, authKey, authSecret, templateId } = props
  const { houseId, roomId } = ids

  if (!authKey || !authSecret) {
    throw new Error('Missing auth key or secret')
  }

  const signature = createSignature({
    authKey,
    authSecret,
    expires,
    templateId,
  })

  // Adding to global `meta` will add it to every file.
  // Every Uppy instance needs a unique ID.
  return new Uppy({
    id: roomId,
    meta: { houseId, roomId },

    locale: Hebrew,
    autoProceed: false,
    restrictions: {
      allowedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
      maxNumberOfFiles: 4,
      minNumberOfFiles: 1,
      minFileSize: 1000,
      maxFileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // 5 MB
    },
  })
    .use(Transloadit, {
      // Import files from Companion using the /import-files Robot
      // importFromUploadURLs: true,
      assemblyOptions(file: any) {
        return {
          params: {
            auth: { key: authKey, expires },
            template_id: templateId,
          },
          signature,
          // You can use these inside your template
          // https://transloadit.com/docs/topics/assembly-instructions/#form-fields-in-instructions
          fields: { roomId: file.meta.roomId, houseId: file.meta.houseId },
          // waitForEncoding: true,
        }
      },
    })
    .use(Compressor)
    .use(Url, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
    .use(GoogleDrive, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
    .use(Facebook, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
    .use(OneDrive, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
    .use(Dropbox, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
    .use(Box, { companionUrl: COMPANION_URL })
}

export default createUppy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
uppy.on('transloadit:complete', (assembly) => {
    ...
});
```

which will fire when the assembly, that was executed, has finished executing.